# PHP Regex double instances of any character

Tags: php, regex

Hi guys can someone help me with this

```
$input_lines= array("asdf","fdas", "asds", "d fm", "dfaa", "aaaa", "aabb", "aaabb");
preg_grep('/a{2}/', explode("\n", $input_lines));
```

Now this returns every string that has atleast 2 a BUT what I want is for it to return every string that has more than 2 character, whatever that character is whether a, b or s
This is the output I want to achieve

```
asds 
dfaa 
aabb 
aaabb
```

Comment: Why you expload `$input_lines` array? `explode() expects parameter 2 to be string`

Comment: That one is from phpliveregex

Comment: This is my code

<?php

// your code goes here
//put input lines into array
//use regexp to filter array
//display result

$inputLines = array("asdf","fdas", "asds", "d fm", "dfaa", "aaaa", "aabb", "aaabb");
// return all array elements
// containing any character in it appearing exactly two times
$matches = preg_grep("/a{2}/",$inputLines);
foreach ($matches as $value) {
  echo "$value <br>";
}

Comment: The regex to achieve display of any character that has double instance of itself in the array is what I need

Comment: Why should `aaaa` not be a match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```php
$input_lines= array("asdf","fdas", "asds", "d fm", "dfaa", "aaaa", "aabb", "aaabb");
print_r(preg_grep('/(\p{L}).*\1/', $input_lines));
```

Note that `'/(\p{L}).*\1/'` regex matches any letter (capturing it into Group 1 with `(\p{L})`) and then matches any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible (with `.*`) and then matches the same char as captured in Group 1. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/asZiY9/1).

Output:

```
Array
(
    [2] => asds
    [4] => dfaa
    [5] => aaaa
    [6] => aabb
    [7] => aaabb
)
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/BSI9Q).

Answer (score 0):

@Emmanuel,
in this solution have a two key function unpack which help we can get the ASCII of each character from give string(that return as array) and array_unique using this we can convert to unique array and then check with it's original array count if it's less than original array than there is repeat character in it. [**Note:** this solution can also work with mix string i.e. characters and numbers e.g *'asw11d'*]

```
<?php
$input_lines= array("asdf","fdas", "asds", "d fm", "dfaa", "aaaa", "aabb", "aaabb");
    
    for($i=0;$i<count($input_lines);$i++)
    {
        
        $ChrFilter= unpack("C*",$input_lines[$i]);
        if(count(array_unique($ChrFilter))<count($ChrFilter))
        {
        echo $input_lines[$i];
        echo '<br>';
        }
        
    }
?>

Out Put:  
asds 
dfaa 
aaaa 
aabb 
aaabb
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using a regex, you can do that:

```
$arr = ["asdf","fdas", "asds", "d fm", "dfaa", "aaaa", "aabb", "aaabb"];

$res = array_filter($arr, fn($s) => strlen($s) > strlen(count_chars($s, 3)));
```